# How to solve a RubyMine "'ruby-debug-ide' isn't installed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I get the error:

```
Cannot start debugger. Gem 'ruby-debug-ide' isn't installed or its executable script 'rdebug-ide' doesn't exist.
```

but all gems were successfuly installed:

```
gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
gem 'debase'
```

I can run 'rdebug-ide' manually:

```
$ rdebug-ide
Using ruby-debug-base 0.2.1
Usage: rdebug-ide is supposed to be called from RDT, NetBeans, RubyMine, or
       the IntelliJ IDEA Ruby plugin.  The command line interface to
       ruby-debug is rdebug.
```

But when I start debugging, RubyMine asks to install the ruby-debug-ide gem. Why?

And, after installation I get:

```
Cannot start debugger. Gem 'ruby-debug-ide' isn't installed or its executable script 'rdebug-ide' doesn't exist.
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.3.

Comment: which version of rubymine/ruby do you have? I think upgrading to the latest versions might solve the problem.

Comment: I'm using 8.0.4 and I've fought with this for a few hours today.

Comment: I have this issue too. any updates?

Answer (score 18):

Here's the actual command that worked for me:

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
```

Comment: Yes, for some reason RubyMine expects a pre-release version of this gem

Answer (score 13):

Complementing Ahsan Ellahi

In your terminal you're probably not running the same ruby version as inside Ruby Mine. You can check this

In Ruby Mine

```
Preferences --> Laguanges and Frameworks --> Ruby SDK and Gems
```

In Terminal

```
$ ruby -v
```

If you're not running the same version, try to set RubyMine to use the same Ruby version that you're running in your terminal. This should solve the problem. Than, if you really want to use another RubyVersion, you will need to go to your terminal, change the Ruby version and manually install both gems

Comment: I think you may have meant for there to be a space in "ruby-v": ruby -v

Answer (score 11):

I have faced this issue when debugging in a `docker-compose` environment. I suspect that RubyMine does not refresh the list of available gem after the SDK is added.

So if you add the SDK then add `ruby-debug-ide` to `Gemfile` you will get the error.

Instead, (re)create the SDK after adding `ruby-debug-ide`.

Comment: there also appears to be a 'Sync Gems and Rubymine Helpers' button now at the top of the remote SDK gem listing

Answer (score 8):

I started getting this after upgrading from 2017.x to 2018.1. In my case, it seems that RubyMine needed a newer version but its error message implied it couldn't find any version and failed to install it. I think it was trying to install it with a different SDK.

Manually installing the latest `ruby-debugger-ide` (in my case the `--pre` flag was necessary) and then restarting RubyMine did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Mac OSX, I couldn't provide the same exact answer for you, but you can find a similar way of achieving this. I'm using Ubuntu with Vagrant, so you may need to adapt it just a little bit.

1. Copy the following gem from RubyMine/rb/gems app folder, please copy the gem related to your ruby runtime and platform, there are different gems for different ruby runtime and platforms, in my case, its:

   - debase-0.3.0.beta7.gem
   - ruby-debug-ide-0.8.0.beta6.gem
2. Install them inside your app host, in my case its vagrant, in your case it could be inside your container, or in your host OS using the following command:

```
gem install --force --local *.gem
```

3. Set breakpoint and start debugging.

It may asks you one more time to install the gem, but then the debug will works for sure.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
gem install debase-ruby_core_source
```

Source: [Cannot install Rubymine Debugger](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000706184-Cannot-install-Rubymine-Debugger?page=1#community_comment_115000603750)

Answer (score 2):

Run `gem uninstall ruby-debug-ide` and run the debugger again. The IDE should prompt you to install the correct versions again.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into RubyMine settings, which `ruby version` and which `gemset` (global/default) it is using. Check out where these required gems are installed and make sure RubyMine is using that gemset where these are installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this after viewing the responses here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206072049-Cannot-start-debugger

The solution at the bottom suggested 'removing all my gems. removing ruby. cleaning up directories and rvm. removing ruby mine, then reinstalling everything'

I started with the easiest of these, which was to reinstall rubymine. That solved it for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13269382)

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Read the next three lines after the link.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Windows 11 running Ubuntu on WSL2.  To solve, I manually copied the relevant files in my %AppData% directory into the corresponding directory in Ubuntu.

I found all the data at:
`C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\RubyMine[VERSION]\ruby_stubs\[NUMBER]\home\[USER]\.gem\ruby\2.7.0`

These files were copied to: `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\[USER]\.gem\ruby\2.7.0`

After doing this, everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue too with Rubymine 8, rvm 1.29.1 and Ruby version 2.3.3 And upgrading the Rubymine version from Rubymine 8 to Rubymine 2016.3 or latest resolves the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check ruby **SDK's** version is right.You can first using rails installer to install everything .

Then using gem to install **rdebug** for ruby 2+.

Make sure **Rubymine's Ruby** version is same to which you have installed.With those all done,you will be able to debug ruby.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to go to Rubymine settings, to the available SDKs, 
remove the SDK, restart Rubymine and add the SDK again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check x286 vs 64 version, both Ruby and Rmine version. I had this problem runnin x86 rubyMine on 64 ruby

Answer (score 0):

A combination of matching the host ide ruby version with the remote SDK version worked for me but required a few additional steps.  I too am running mac os as my host (running mohave)

1. the remote environment setup in preferences -> ruby sdk and gems must have the same version as the remote target, including any gems installed.

NOTE: I had to re-install the bundler gem on both host and remote host to get the gem manager to install things auto-majically.

2. the project environment must be changed to use the same version as the remote host as well.  this is in File -> preferences for new projects -> ruby sdk and gems.

NOTE: I also had to set the default RVM on my local host and remote host and unset the previous version as default in the local host preferences.

Once I did this I was able to get gems in sync and remote debugger to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 18 something, RubyMine version 2020.3. Had this issue. None of these suggestions worked for me, same error no matter what did. I was using RVM, and ruby 2.6 and 2.7, switched back and forth a cleaning and reinstalling gems along thew way, both debase and ruby-debug-ide were installed according to the gem list. Settings in rubymine matched "ruby -v" from the command line. VSCode worked perfectly with this setup.

In the end i removed RVM and all the ruby versions, installed ruby via rbenv, installed ruby 2.6.5 and that worked like a charm.

I think this error is generated for multiple reasons with no real way to figure out which reason for your specific instance. I would like to encourage jetbrains to generate more debug information on errors like this, or if you are generating error information, point out where it is when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

```
1. /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
2. brew install ruby
3. echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

if you get unshallow error on any step then first try:

```
1. git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
2. git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow
3. /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
4. brew install ruby
5. echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Lastly restart the terminal and check .bash_profile:

```
 - nano ~/.bash_profile
```

If you see the path variable, just close it. Otherwise it means something went wrong :/.

The last step is to open

RubyMine -> Preferences -> Language and Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems -> select the newest ruby version and apply.

You may need to update ruby version from the gemfile.

And it should be done!